# move files with delay 3 seconds using dos command

Tags: command-line

I have a 1,760 files with a file name of 1.txt - 1760.txt

I want to move the files in a different folder with delay in order

currently I'm using

```
 move d:\temp\1.txt d:\new\1.txt
 move d:\temp\2.txt d:\new\2.txt
 move d:\temp\3.txt d:\new\3.txt
 move d:\temp\4.txt d:\new\4.txt
 move d:\temp\5.txt d:\new\5.txt
 move d:\temp\6.txt d:\new\6.txt
 move d:\temp\7.txt d:\new\7.txt
 move d:\temp\8.txt d:\new\8.txt
 move d:\temp\9.txt d:\new\9.txt
 move d:\temp\10.txt d:\new\10.txt
 move d:\temp\11.txt d:\new\11.txt
```

but the result there are case 10.txt and 11.txt move first

Appreciate all you help.

Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> move d:\temp\1.txt d:\new\1.txt
>   choice /C yn /D Y /T 3
>   move d:\temp\2.txt d:\new\2.txt
>   choice /C yn /D Y /T 3
>   move d:\temp\3.txt d:\new\3.txt
>   choice /C yn /D Y /T 3

etc.  If my memory is serving me correctly, `Choice` was introduced in MS-DOS 6.  (Some of those command line parameters might be newer than that.)

I find it highly likely that your files might be in the order you desire, but you are sorting them alphanumerically (causing "10" to appear before "2", just like "ao" appears before "b").

I just did some experimenting:

> echo a > a
>   echo c > c
>   echo b > b

Now I thought COMMAND.COM (and likely CMD) would default to an unordered sort.  But, just to be thorough, I used JPSoftware's TCMD, which supports a /OU option (to DIR) which explicitly declares that an unordered sort is desired.  And that still showed me a, then b, then c

The most logical conclusion is that my operating system (currently on a Windows 10 system) is choosing to store the files on the disk in a sorted way.  This is overriding the effects of my attempts to tell programs that the programs shouldn't be sorting the results of what gets read from the disk.

Comment: More likely the filesystem. NTFS directories are sorted on disk, FAT\* are not.

Answer (score 0):

You suggest the filenames are consecutive numbers 1 to 1170, but say there are 1760 total. There are not 1760 integers in the range 1 to 1170. Assuming you do want 1 to 1170, in numeric order:

`FOR /L %i (1,1,1170) DO ( MOVE d:\temp\%i.txt d:\new & timeout /nobreak 3 >NUL )`

(If used inside a `.bat` file rather than interactive, double the percent signs.)

Comment: Hi Dave Thompson, 

Sorry its a typo it should be 1,760 not 1,170

Andrew